# layout как правильно прописать

Tags: framework, php, yii, layout

Значит так.

Есть админка на yii.

Форма входа в админку грузится при условии что пользователь не авторизован. при авторизации кидаем его на нужную страницу.

Внимаени Вопрос!

У меня несколько layout, один это форма входа в админку. Второй layoutэто шаблон самой админки. Так вот

Обязательно перед каждым   render прописывать нужный мне layout? или можно как-то иначе сделать?

```
 $this->layout="/layouts/main";
 $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
```

**//upd и всё-таки помощь некоторая нужна.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наличие layout'а проверяется в порядке очередности:

- Сначала в `CController::$layout`
- Затем, если используется модуль, в `CWebModule::$layout`
- И в последнюю очередь в `CWebApplication::$layout`

Соответственно, если у вас админка вынесена в отдельный модуль, то можете выставить layout в модуле, иначе в соответствующем контроллере и переопределять его только при выводе формы входа.

Comment: ну вот, good спасибос и респектос :) гемора стало на 5 строк меньше.